# Error: Codesign failed with exit code 1. no duplicate plists found

Tags: iphone, provisioning, info.plist

I'm having the same dilemma. I recently upgraded my 3GS to 4.0 software and it will load under 3.1 but will not load on 4.0.  I get this error...

> codesign failed with exit code 1.

The other question I have is when I loaded the new 4.0, my other build versions disappeared. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

I also was struggling with the 'Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1' error message.

Here is how I solved it

Right-click on info.plist (or whatever your application plist name is) look at it's targets. Make sure the box to the left is UNCHECKED. This is the default state.

Targeting the files don't work fine for the info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It had to do with my info.plist